# Cookie can not be sent to server

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to learn C++ network programming with POCO C++ Library. I add a cookie to a response object and return back to the client. I can find the cookie value through firebug (using Firefox), but by js code:`alert(document.cookie)`, it can not display that cookie information and also this cookie can not be sent to server.

```
Set-Cookie:name=testname; domain=testacshserver.com; path=/;expires=Tue, 23 Apr 2013 10:54:43 GMT; secure; HttpOnly
```

It is the same situation when I use IE9.

Comment: Maybe should be the expires date in the future.

Comment: It says `HttpOnly` so you shouldn't be able to access it via JS.

Comment: @Quentin Set-Cookie:name=testname; domain=testacshserver.com; path=/; expires=Tue, 23 Apr 2013 12:05:10 GMT; secure
even HttpOnly is not set, it's the same

Comment: @rekire the max-age is set 1h, so i do not think there is anything wrong about epires date

Comment: You also transmit `secure` that means that the cookie should be only transmitted via HTTPS. Do you use HTTPS oder HTTP?

Comment: @rekire thanks, it works if secure is not set, i use http

Comment: @YongpanZhang you are welcome. I also added this as an answer just for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

You need to omit the parts `secure` for transmit only via HTTPS and `HttpOnly` which makes a cookie unaccessable from JavaScript. So you just need to transmit:

```
Set-Cookie:name=testname; domain=testacshserver.com; path=/;expires=Tue, 23 Apr 2013 10:54:43 GMT
```